# Oracle 12c Adding Column to table without default value taking really long

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, alter-table

I'm trying to add a new column to an existing table of approximately 30,000 rows in our test Oracle 12c R2 environment, but it has been running for over an hour and completely locked up SQL Developer

Here is the basic syntax that I used. I didn't specify any default value since one isn't needed and should be NULL by default.

```
ALTER TABLE "Schema"."Table" ADD "C_C6" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)
```

I tried looking up this issue, but most cases seem to refer to issues where people are trying to specify default values, which I'm not doing.

I have also temporarily disable any triggers that I had on the table prior to running the Alter Table statement

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you are not being blocked by another session.  If there are any uncommitted DML statements on your table, your `ALTER TABLE` will just wait.  Normally, a DDL statement will result in "ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired" if it cannot get an exclusive lock on the table, but not `ALTER TABLE... ADD COLUMN` (because it is not covered by an exclusive DDL lock on the table).

Comment: It's not only any uncommited DML statements, as @MatthewMcPeak said. Any lock on the table (like open cursors from client applications) will cause the `ALTER TABLE` to wait. (Unless Oracle and Sql Anywhere behave differently in this case.) This might even be an open window in your SQL Developer.

Comment: OK it looks like there may have been a blocking issue with another session. I had the user close the application, but now i have to for my alter table statement to rollback because i killed the session since it was killing performance on the server and the CPU was staying at 99%

Comment: Any recommendations on how to avoid this on a production system?

Comment: "Avoid this"?  What do you want to have happen?

Comment: How do i go about being able to add the column to the table without everything locking up and and maxing out CPU and Memory on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want  [Edition-Based Redefinition](https://www.oracle.com/partners/campaign/o20asktom-098897.html) that allows you to create a new edition of the database, create a view of the table in the old edition, rename the table in the old edition, and in the new edition add the column to the renamed table, and then migrate the data from the old edition to the new edition.  Tom Kyte gives a full explanation at the link above.  The only downtime will be a few minutes to rename the table in the old edition.  And you have full control over how you migrated the data so you won't bog things down, but for a 30,000 row table it is just likely the locks were spinning the CPU.